# How to write update query including select, joins and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have two tables in my database: `tweets` and `users`.

In the `users` table, I have three columns named "`id`" (ID of the user), "`datetime_created_at`" (datetime when the user was added to the database) and "`datetime_modified_at`" (last datetime when the user attributes were modified).

In the `tweets` table I have two columns: "`id`" (ID of the tweet) and "`datetime`" (datetime when this tweet was posted).

In the `users` table, I have NULL values in the `datetime_modified_at` column for some users so, to fill it, I decided to put the datetime of the last tweet that user posted when that value is NULL but `datetime_created_at` does have a not NULL value. For example, if UserA has two tweets with dateA and dateB respectevely, and dateB > dateA, I expect to fill the NULL value like this: `datetime_modified_at` = dateB.

For this, I wrote the following query:

```
update users
set datetime_modified_at = max_datetime
from (
    select users.id, max(tweets.datetime) as max_datetime from users 
    inner join tweets on users.id = tweets.user_id
    where users.datetime_created_at is not NULL and users.datetime_modified_at is NULL
    group by users.id
)  Grouped
where users.datetime_created_at is not NULL and users.datetime_modified_at is NULL
```

The problem with this query is that every `datetime_modified_at` of every user that fits this condition (`where users.datetime_created_at is not NULL and users.datetime_modified_at is NULL`) is filled with the same value (for example "2022-08-03 22:22:42", and not the actual max datetime for each user).

How should I write this query to obtain this result?

Comment: See [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You should do update where, do select from users table first only then you inner join the table so that it can update to the respective id.

```
update users
set datetime_modified_at = max_datetime
from 
users INNER JOIN
(
    select users.id, max(tweets.datetime) as max_datetime from users 
    inner join tweets on users.id = tweets.user_id
    where users.datetime_created_at is not NULL and users.datetime_modified_at is NULL
    group by users.id
)  Grouped ON users.id = grouped.id
where users.datetime_created_at is not NULL and users.datetime_modified_at is NULL
```